# Can someone point to some pre Holocaust (the older the better) Sefarim that address antisemitism in depth?

Tags: history, jewish-books, anti-semitism

Considering all the Jew hatred experienced in every generation from persecution & exile to horrors like Hadrian’s Decrees, the crusades, blood libels, Inquisitions, & pogroms etc one would think that many prominent Jewish leaders throughout the ages would have written in depth about the spiritual & metaphysical components & roots animating this seemingly never ending nightmarish phenomenon but I’m having trouble finding many Sefarim particularly from prominent voices that really discuss this issue. Any thoughts guiding me in the right direction would be deeply appreciated.
Thanks & Keep Shining!

Answer (score 2):

Gemara Megillah daf 13b the Talmud has a drash of Haman's explanation to King Achashverosh in Esther chapter 3 about why he should kill the Jews. It's shocking how timeless many of these complaints are. Clearly the Rabbis of the Talmud well understood things antisemites would complain about, either because antisemites were saying this at the time or Text and translation from Sefaria:

״יֶשְׁנוֹ עַם אֶחָד״, אָמַר רָבָא: לֵיכָּא דְּיָדַע לִישָּׁנָא בִּישָׁא כְּהָמָן. אֲמַר לֵיהּ: תָּא נִיכַלִּינְהוּ. אֲמַר לֵיהּ: מִסְתְּפֵינָא מֵאֱלָהַיְהוּ דְּלָא לֶיעְבֵּיד בִּי כְּדַעֲבַד בְּקַמָּאֵי. אֲמַר לֵיהּ: [״יֶשְׁנוֹ״ —] יָשְׁנוּ מִן הַמִּצְוֹת.
אֲמַר לֵיהּ: אִית בְּהוּ רַבָּנַן. אֲמַר לֵיהּ: עַם אֶחָד הֵן.
שֶׁמָּא תֹּאמַר, קָרְחָה אֲנִי עוֹשֶׂה בְּמַלְכוּתֶךָ — מְפוּזָּרִין הֵם בֵּין הָעַמִּים. שֶׁמָּא תֹּאמַר: אִית הֲנָאָה מִינַּיְיהוּ — ״מְפוֹרָד״, כִּפְרֵידָה זוֹ שֶׁאֵינָהּ עוֹשָׂה פֵּירוֹת. וְשֶׁמָּא תֹּאמַר, אִיכָּא מְדִינְתָּא מִינַּיְיהוּ — תַּלְמוּד לוֹמַר: ״בְּכׇל מְדִינוֹת מַלְכוּתֶךָ״.
״וְדָתֵיהֶם שׁוֹנוֹת מִכׇּל עָם״, דְּלָא אָכְלִי מִינַּן וְלָא נָסְבִי מִינַּן וְלָא מִנַּסְבִי לַן. ״וְאֶת דָּתֵי הַמֶּלֶךְ אֵינָם עוֹשִׂים״, דְּמַפְּקִי לְכוּלָּא שַׁתָּא בְּשִׁהֵי פִּהֵי. ״וְלַמֶּלֶךְ אֵין שֹׁוֶה לְהַנִּיחָם״, דְּאָכְלוּ וְשָׁתוּ וּמְבַזּוּ לֵיהּ לְמַלְכָּא, וַאֲפִילּוּ נוֹפֵל זְבוּב בְּכוֹסוֹ שֶׁל אֶחָד מֵהֶן — זוֹרְקוֹ וְשׁוֹתֵהוּ, וְאִם אֲדוֹנִי הַמֶּלֶךְ נוֹגֵעַ בְּכוֹסוֹ שֶׁל אֶחָד מֵהֶן — חוֹבְטוֹ בַּקַּרְקַע וְאֵינוֹ שׁוֹתֵהוּ.

> Haman said to Ahasuerus: “There is [yeshno] one people scattered abroad [mefuzar] and dispersed [meforad] among the peoples in all the provinces of your kingdom; and their laws are diverse from those of every people; nor do they keep the king’s laws; therefore it does not profit the king to tolerate them” (Esther 3:8). Rava said: There was none who knew how to slander like Haman, as in his request to the king he included responses to all the reasons Ahasuerus might be reluctant to destroy the Jewish people. He said to Ahasuerus: Let us destroy them. Ahasuerus said to him: I am afraid of their God, lest He do to me as He did to those who stood against them before me. Haman said to him: They have been asleep [yashnu] with respect to the mitzvot, having ceased to observe the mitzvot, and, therefore there is no reason to fear.
> Ahasuerus said to him: There are the Sages among them who observe the mitzvot. Haman said to him: They are one people, i.e., they are all the same; nobody observes the mitzvot.
> Haman continued with his next response as expressed in the verse: Perhaps you will say that I am making a bald spot in your kingdom, i.e., you fear that if an entire nation is wiped out there will be a desolate area within the kingdom. There is no need to worry, though, as they are scattered [mefuzarin] among the peoples, and eradicating them will not result in the creation of an unpopulated zone in the area where they had once lived. Furthermore, perhaps you will say that there is benefit from them; but this nation is meforad, like this barren mule [pereida] that cannot bear offspring, and there is no benefit to be gained from them. And perhaps you will say that there is at least a province that is filled with them. Therefore the verse states that they are scattered “in all the provinces of your kingdom” (Esther 3:8), and they do not inhabit one place.
> Haman continued: “And their laws are diverse from those of every people” (Esther 3:8), as they do not eat from our food, nor do they marry from our women, nor do they marry off their women to us. “Nor do they keep the king’s laws” (Esther 3:8). They spend the entire year in idleness, as they are constantly saying: Shehi pehi, an acronym for: It is Shabbat today [Shabbat hayom]; it is Passover today [Pesaḥ hayom]. The verse continues: “Therefore it does not profit the king to tolerate them,” as they eat and drink and scorn the throne. And a proof of this is that even if a fly falls into the cup of one of them, he will throw the fly out and drink the wine it fell into, but if my master the king were to touch the glass of one of them, he would throw it to the ground, and would not drink it, since it is prohibited to drink wine that was touched by a gentile.

There are also other places in the Talmud that discuss why certain people hate the Jews or certain arguments against the Jews. In general, however, I think Judaism has tended to be more inward looking. I also wonder whether such works would have been further bait for censorship and Jew-haters. I imagine if a Jew tried to write "why the Christians hate the Jews" there's a good chance it would be taken as anti-Christian.

Comment: Par'oh's advisors gave the classic reason for anti-Semitism as recorded in the chumash in Sh'mot 1:10

Comment: @rosends could you explain?

Answer (score 2):

The Netziv wrote a work on this topic titled *She'eir Yisroel*, available [here.](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=59593&st=&pgnum=280)